# Jupyter single line bash to python variable

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I really like the ability of jupyter to mix bash commands inline like this:

```
for d in list_of_dirs:
    ! ls {d}
```

However, is there any way to get the output of one of these inline commands to be assigned to a python variable? For example as a python list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

Code:

```py
python_list = []
for d in list_of_dirs:
    temp_list = !ls {d}
    python_list.extend(temp_list)
```

Comment: Ah! I feel stupid now for not trying to just directly assign it to a variable. Thanks!! Will accept this when it allows.

Comment: It's Python! Use pseudo-code if you are not sure!))

Answer (score 4):

This works well

```
for d in list_of_dirs:
    out = !'ls {0}'.format('d')
```

Answer (score 1):

os.popen works for this. popen - opens a pipe to or from command. The return value is an open file object connected to the pipe, which can be read. split('\n') converts the output to list

```
import os
list_of_ls = os.popen("ls").read().split('\n')
print list_of_ls
```

Comment: hmm interesting alternative, thank you. If it turns out that assigning `!` output to a variable directly isn't possible I'll select this answer!